# R pivot table from long to wide format

Tags: r, pivot-table

I am creating a table with two headers (as shown in the desired output) but its not in the correct order. How do I order the columns and sort the year from most recent to the oldest

My data:

```
Country Year A B
France  1998    2   1
France  1999    3   4
France  2000    4   4
Newzealand  1999    4   0
Newzealand  2000    0   0
Ireland 1998    5   1
Ireland 1999    1   1
Ireland 2000    1   1
```

Desired Output:
[image]

My code:

```
data %>%
  select(Country, Year, A, B) %>%
  pivot_wider( names_from = Year,
              values_from = c("A", "B"), values_fill = 0) %>%
  as_flextable() %>%
  separate_header()
```

This code yields table in the following format
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may change the name order with 'Year' values as prefix and the value column names as suffix with `names_glue`.  In addition, `names_vary` uses by default "fastest", change it to "slowest" to reorder the names in `value1_name1, value2_name1, ...` order and then convert to `flextable` and split the header at delimiter `_`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(flextable)
data %>%
    select(Country, Year, A, B) %>%
    pivot_wider( names_from = Year,
             values_from = c("A", "B"),
   values_fill = 0, names_glue = "{Year}_{.value}", names_vary = "slowest") %>%
    flextable() %>% 
   separate_header()
```

-output

[image]